# Writing an R package that is different per architecture

Tags: r, 32bit-64bit

I am writing an R package in which you can make networks and output them in different file-types. I found the package SVGRTipsDevice which can be used to create SVG pictures containing tooltips and hyperlinks, which I really like. I have included this in my package as one of the options to output in, making it not an essential part of my package, but a part of it nonetheless (one that I want to keep).

The problem now is, that this package is for 32bit users only. Because my package depends on it 64bit users are not able to install it. it seems that I either have to make my package 32bit-only as well or remove the SVG abilities (currently I chose the latter to upload to CRAN, with a link to the full package on my site).

Is there any way to do this differently? Like making the package installable for anyone but only make the SVG functionality available for 32bit users?

Comment: When you say "making it not an essential part of my package, but a part of it" do you build your package with SVGRTipsDevice in Suggests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages listed in the Suggests: or Enhances: field of the DESCRIPTION file of your package do not need to be installed on the user's system for your package to be installed, so that 32/64 bit users can install your package. Rather than testing for bit-ness, you might `ok <- suppressWarnings(require(SVGToolTips)))`, maybe in `.onLoad` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. It's my first package and I am making some rookie mistakes.

Answer (score 6):

easiest way I can think of is to check `Sys.info()` for the machine type:

So on my machine:

```
 Sys.info()["machine"]
 machine 
"x86_64"
```

**EDIT** I believe that tells us the architecture of the hardware, not whether R is 32 or 64 bit. So if a user had 64 bit hardware and was running 32 bit R, the above code would still return `x86_64` As Sacha pointed out to me, a better solution is to run:

```
R.Version()$arch
[1] "x86_64"
```

So you can see I'm running a 64 bit OS AND I am running the 64 bit version of R.

Comment: Thanks, this should be very useful!

Comment: You can get information on the architecture of R with: R.Version()$arch

Comment: Sacha, that's a really good point. I edited my response. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a packagename-32bit package also with the extra functionality.